# Gradle multi-project configuration order management

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

**Edit:**
After looking around in Gradle sources this behaviour seems intended and is triggered by using `getByPath`, `getByName`, `findByPath` and `findByName` methods on task containers, but apparently only if the provided argument value represents a task name and not a task path (that is, if it doesn't contain the ':' path separator).

See 
[this link to TaskContainer implementation](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/f766aa649d6336c7dfb9d138c05fa7670a604416/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/DefaultTaskContainer.java#L296)
where a call to `projectAccessListener.beforeRequestingTaskByPath(project);` is done before actually accessing the tasks of the project,
and also 
[this link to ProjectAccessListener implementation](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/f766aa649d6336c7dfb9d138c05fa7670a604416/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/project/DefaultProjectAccessListener.java#L23)
where the project is actually evaluated.

I'm trying to better understand the available ways to manage project configuration order. The examples are somewhat lengthy but I feel are necessary to set the context of the question.

#### Setup

Suppose we have a very basic setup with one root project and one subproject:

```
master
+--- build.gradle
+--- settings.gradle
+--- lib
 \--- build.gradle
```

`settings.gradle`

```
include 'lib'
rootProject.name = 'master'
```

`build.gradle`

```
println "${project.name} config start"
println "${project.name} config done"
```

`lib/build.gradle`

```
println "${project.name} config start"
println "${project.name} config done"
```

#### Base case

If we execute `gradle projects` in the top level directory we'll see the following evaluation order:

```
master config start
master config done
lib config start
lib config done
```

which is expected since the Gradle documentation says the projects are configured in the top-down order:

> The default configuration order is top down, which is usually what is needed.

#### evaluationDependsOn

There's a documented way to change the order via evaluationDependsOn method:

`build.gradle`

```
println "${project.name} config start"
evaluationDependsOn(':lib')
println "${project.name} config done"
```

The output:

```
master config start
lib config start
lib config done
master config done
```

So `evaluationDependsOn` basically loads the `'lib'` build script, configures it and then resumes master project configuration.

#### Referencing subproject from master

Now suppose we'll inject a property into the lib project:

`build.gradle`

```
println "${project.name} config start"
project(':lib').ext.flag = true
println "${project.name} config done"
```

`lib/build.gradle`

```
println "${project.name} config start"
println "Property value: ${project.flag}"
println "${project.name} config done"
```

The output will be as follows:

```
master config start
master config done
lib config start
Property value: true
lib config done
```

So, the evaluation order was unaffected by explicitly referencing the subproject (`project(':lib')`) inside the master project and the property injection succeeded.

#### Adding a task to the subproject

Now we'll add a task to the subproject and reference it from the master project:

`build.gradle`

```
println "${project.name} config start"
tasks.getByPath(':lib:action').doLast { println "injected task action" }
println "${project.name} config done"
```

`lib/build.gradle`

```
println "${project.name} config start"
tasks.create('action') {
    println ":lib:action configuration started"
}
println "${project.name} config done"
```

The output is:

```
master config start
lib config start
:lib:action configuration started
lib config done
master config done
```

We see that the evaluation order was changed: the access to the subproject's  task forced full configuration of the subproject before master configuration completed.

#### Question

Now to the actual question:

In Gradle docs I was unable to find any thorough description of which actions and commands change the project configuration order (apart from obvious `evaluationDependsOn` and `evaluationDependsOnChildren`).
Is there any available information regarding this topic? Why is accessing the subproject and its properties doesn't force its configuration, while accessing the tasks does?

Comment: Very interesting discovery! You may describe this behaviour in an issue on the Gradle repository at GitHub, maybe the developers can explain the reasons and whether this is planned or not. Knowing only the public API I have no idea why Gradle behaves this way, especially if one knows the common problem that a task is created after one tries to access it.

Comment: @lu.koerfer, could you please elaborate on the issue of accessing the task that doesn't exist?

Comment: This is great thank you.  It gives a great example of how to use evaluationDependsOn and illustrates other workarounds and demonstrates thought and effort all things that should prompt folks to hit the up arrow!  

ordering gradle's config time order is a black art, and while the tips here are great, they start to fail if you have a doubly nested multiproject build eg, rootP->subPX and want one sub project to happen in a particular order.

Kudos for the effort and ideas to move forward on.